# c++ Count the occurrence of each pair of element in txt file

Tags: c++

I have text file as:

4 1 2 3 4

3 3 1 2

3 4 2 1

2 4 3

where the first element in each row represent the total number of elements in each row

I want to count the occurrence of each pair of element and print the result, such that:

(1,2) = 3 times

so I don't need to count and print (2,1)

the final result has to be:

1 2 = 3

1 3 = 3

1 4 = 2

2 3 = 2

2 4 = 2

3 4 = 2

this  is the code so far:

```
//global values:
    int count2[10][10]; // to store the count of  occurrence of each pair           
    int pair2[10][10];// to store the pair of element
    int Totalnum; // total number of elements in txt file=4 
    int TotLines; //    total number of lines in txt file=4

    // main fun
    int RowSize;
    int item1, item2;
    int maxSize = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j, k;


// Initialize
count2[10][10] = (int )malloc(sizeof(int)* Totalnum);
pair2[10][10] = (int )malloc(sizeof(int)*  Totalnum);
if ((count2 == NULL) || (pair2 == NULL)) {
    cout << "out of memory\n";
    exit(1);
}

for (i = 0; i <  Totalnum; i++)
for (j = 0; j <  Totalnum; j++){
    count2[i][j] = 0;
    pair2[i][j] =0; 
}

/* scan DB to count the frequency of each pair item */

if ((fp = fopen(dataFile, "r")) == NULL) // Database file
{
    cout << "Can't open data file " << dataFile << "\n";
    exit(1);
}

/* Scan each line of the DB */
for (i = 0; i < TotLines; i++) 
{
    /* Read the row size */
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &RowSize);


    /* Read the items in the row*/
    for (j = 0; j < RowSize; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &item1);
        for (k = j + 1; k < RowSize; k++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &item2);
            if (pair2[item1][item2] == pair2[item2][item1])
            {
                count2[item1][item2] ++;
                count2[item2][item1] = count2[item1][item2];
            }
            else
                count2[item1][item2]++;
       }
    }

}
fclose(fp);

for (j = 0; j <= Totalnum; j++){
    for (k = j + 1; k <= Totalnum; k++)
        printf("%d  [%d] ", pair2[j][k], count2[j][k]);
            cout <<  "\n";
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line causes the issue?

Comment: it gives me wrong results

Comment: One issue is you are using `malloc` with an array that already has storage space (and you do this twice).

Comment: How do you handle the input case "3 3 1 2"?  Is this one pair or many?

Comment: Where do you assign values to `pair[item1][item2]`?  You REALLY need to single step this with a debugger.

Comment: "3 3 1 2" = the first element means, this row has 3 elements (3 and 1 and 2)

Comment: So, how do you generate pairs with 3 numbers?  My understanding is that a *pair* is two numbers.

Comment: Code `// Initialize ... exit(1); }` is ill formed and not needed.  `count2, pair2` already have memory.

Comment: @MEEM This is (poor) C, not C++. Use streams and containers to make your life more easy! Once you do so, it will even become straightforward to simplify the input format by leaving out the size-indicators. Instead, you can use `getline` and `stringstream`'s.

Comment: could you please give me an example? IF I have txt file with multi lines(ex: 1 0.933 2 0.865 3 0.919) such that each point has prob. so i create array of linked list as the following: http://ideone.com/loYZmC

Comment: the problem is: getline takes every line as string, and I don't know how to split the string such that: Trans[1]=>Item=1,  Trans[1]->prob=0.933, Trans[1]=>Item->next=2, Trans[1]=>prob->next=0.865 ... etc, instead I just got the first element and its prob. in each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to map the pair to a counter. Here is what it would look like:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> pairToCount;

while (in >> a >> b)
{
    auto it = pairToCount.find(std::make_pair(b, a));

    ++pairToCount[
        (it != pairToCount.end()) ? std::make_pair(b, a)
                                  : std::make_pair(a, b) ];
}

for (const auto& p : pairToCount)
{
    std::cout << "(" << p.first.first << " " << p.first.second << ") = "
                                             << p.second << '\n';
}
```

[**Here is a Live Demo.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d814d3e3cf71fd)

Comment: Haven't tested this so I could be wrong. I think you should also overload `operator==` (or `operator<`, whichever is used to figure out if they are the same) on the pair of ints in order to make sure that {2,1} and {1,2} are considered the same pair.

Comment: thank you, i will try it. using map is new for me, thanks for the information

Comment: @499602D2 in his example he's doing just that... {1,2} and {2,1} are in the same bin.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks :-) There is another small issue with the code though. The way you extract the integers from the stream causes only the n'th and (n+1)th integers to be paired up, for **even** n (thus skipping the other half of the pairs). One solution would be to extract them one by one and keep the previous value in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start counting the pairs, you must identify them.

Your requirements are lacking in how pairs are generated from the data row.
Example 1, using 4 1 2 3 4
  Are the pairs <1,2> <3,4>?
  Or <1,2> <2, 3> <3, 4>?
  Or all permuations:
     <1, 1> <1, 2> <1, 3> <1, 4>,
     <2, 1> <2, 2> <2, 3> <2, 4>,
     <3, 1> <3, 2> <3, 3> <3, 4>,
     <4, 1> <4, 2> <4, 3> <4, 4>?

Once you decide how to generate the pairs, using a `std::map` would be easier for counting.

Comment: 1st line = Using 4 1 2 3 4
Pairs are generated like:
<1, 2> <1, 3> <1, 4>,
<2, 3> <2, 4>,
<3, 4>,

2nd line = Using 3 3 1 2 
Pairs are generated like:
<3, 1> <3, 2> <1, 2>,

3rd line Using  3 4 2 1 
Pairs are generated like:
<4, 2> <4, 1> <2, 1>,

4th line = Using 2 4 3 
Pairs are generated like:
<4, 3> 

So when we do count for example (element 1 with element 2):
We will find:
<1, 2> 1st line  +  <1, 2> 2nd line + <2, 1> + 0 4th line = 3 times
So we don’t care if the order {1,2} or {2,1}. Just how many times they appear together in all lines